# cURL -F parameters and HttpURLConnection to Upload Image on Android to Amazon S3

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection, url-parameters

How to post cURL with -F parameters using HttpURLConnection to upload jpeg image? I would like to use this code on my Android App.

This is the cURL post request:

```
curl -X POST 
  -F "Content-Type=image/jpeg" 
  -F "Expires=Wed, 30 Sep 2015 13:29:39 GMT" 
  -F "acl=authenticated-read" 
  -F "key=76101edd87fe4b299ff41f63633bf9c100" 
  -F "policy=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" 
  -F "success_action_status=201" 
  -F "x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" 
  -F "x-amz-credential=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A/20150930/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" 
  -F "x-amz-date=20150930T122939Z" 
  -F "x-amz-signature=eee18ae3d47a745bccc9007d1b7b1679e855becb44b1928bb710428e18e397a8"      -F "file=@user_new_avatar.jpg"  
https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

I am trying this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String url_ = "https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?";

            // DECODED PARAMETERS   
            String parameters = "Content-Type=image/jpeg&Expires=Sun, 17 Jan 2016 04:56:07 GMT&acl=authenticated-read&key=9933971e9cb9403a92802679b89d8f3500&policy=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&success_action_status=201&x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&x-amz-credential=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A/20160117/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&x-amz-date=20160117T035607Z&x-amz-signature=d66644c385066eb492cd50424eec072c0c7d9eeb3f392715ba2e94fd337b9f17&file=@/tmp/test.jpeg";

            URL url = new URL(url_ + parameters);

            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace(); // show exception details
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I get this response:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?Content-Type=image/jpeg&Expires=Sun, 17 Jan 2016 04:56:07 GMT&acl=authenticated-read&key=9933971e9cb9403a92802679b89d8f3500&policy=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&success_action_status=201&x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&x-amz-credential=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A/20160117/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&x-amz-date=20160117T035607Z&x-amz-signature=d66644c385066eb492cd50424eec072c0c7d9eeb3f392715ba2e94fd337b9f17&file=@/tmp/test.jpeg
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1628)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at user.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

Also, I am trying this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String url_ = "https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?";

            // NOW ENCODING THE PARAMETERS  
            String parameters = URLEncoder.encode("Content-Type=image/jpeg&Expires=Sun, 17 Jan 2016 04:56:07 GMT&acl=authenticated-read&key=9933971e9cb9403a92802679b89d8f3500&policy=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&success_action_status=201&x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&x-amz-credential=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A/20160117/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&x-amz-date=20160117T035607Z&x-amz-signature=d66644c385066eb492cd50424eec072c0c7d9eeb3f392715ba2e94fd337b9f17&file=@/tmp/test.jpeg");

            URL url = new URL(url_ + parameters);

            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace(); // show exception details
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I get this response:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 412 for URL: https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?Content-Type%3Dimage%2Fjpeg%26Expires%3DSun%2C+17+Jan+2016+04%3A56%3A07+GMT%26acl%3Dauthenticated-read%26key%3D9933971e9cb9403a92802679b89d8f3500%26policy%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%3D%26success_action_status%3D201%26x-amz-algorithm%3DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%26x-amz-credential%3DAKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A%2F20160117%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request%26x-amz-date%3D20160117T035607Z%26x-amz-signature%3Dd66644c385066eb492cd50424eec072c0c7d9eeb3f392715ba2e94fd337b9f17%26file%3D%40%2Ftmp%2Ftest.jpeg
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1628)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at user.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Use an HTTP client library with multipart support. That is the type of request your cURL request it. Look at [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Comment: @peeskillet "HttpClient does not support multipart file upload out of the box" - quote from [http://wwwilpower.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/android-file-upload-to-amazon-s3-with.html]

Comment: Maybe not in the core dependency. You need the httpmime dependency to go along with it. See [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload) along with the linked github project in the "conclusion"